# Loss of numpy array dimensions when save and retrieve from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a `numpy.array` data type and I want to write it to a .csv file with pandas, so I run this:

```
data = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(data)
print((data.shape))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['content'])
df.loc[0, 'content'] = data
df.to_csv('data.csv', index = False)
print(df.head())

>>> [1 2 3 4 5 6]
>>> (6,)
>>>                content
     0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

As seen in the output, the dimensions of the numpy array is (6,).
But the problem is that when I retrieve it from .csv file array dimension loss and change to ()

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
val = numpy.array(data['content'][0])
print(val.shape)
print(val)
>>> ()
>>> [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [46]: import pandas as pd
In [47]: data = np.arange(1,7)
In [48]: data.shape
Out[48]: (6,)
```

The original dataframe:

```
In [49]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['content'])
    ...: df.loc[0, 'content'] = data
In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
              content
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [52]: df.to_numpy()
Out[52]: array([[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]], dtype=object)
```

`to_numpy` from a dataframe produces a 2d array, here with 1 element, and that element is an array ifself.

```
In [54]: df.to_numpy()[0,0]
Out[54]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Look at the full file, not just the head:

```
In [55]: df.to_csv('data.csv', index = False)
In [56]: cat data.csv
content
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

That 2nd line is  the `str(data)` display - with `[]` and no commas

`read_csv` loads that as a string.  It does not try convert it to an array; it can't.

```
In [57]: d = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
In [58]: d
Out[58]: 
         content
0  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
In [59]: d.to_numpy()
Out[59]: array([['[1 2 3 4 5 6]']], dtype=object)
In [60]: d.to_numpy()[0,0]
Out[60]: '[1 2 3 4 5 6]'
```

`csv` is not a good format for saving a dataframe that contains objects such as arrays or lists as elements.  It only works well for elements that are simple numbers and strings.